# How would I implement stacking properties to draggable objects in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How would I implement stacking properties to draggable `div`s in JQuery UI?

I you do not understand what exactly I am talking about, check this out: http://qtip2.com/demos#section-stacking

As you can see, in the link above, as you `hover` over the "tips", the respective tip will go to the top(which looks much like incresing the `z-index`).

How would I do this if I had 3 `div`s which are draggable?

Dumie example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height:100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="draggable">I am draggable</div>
<div id="div2" class="draggable">I am draggable too!</div>
<div id="div3" class="draggable">Don't forget about me!</div>
```

When I click any of the `div`s, I want them to come to the front(or do something like increasing the `z-index`).

Now I do not have any idea of how to do this, please do help and comment! :)

Comment: you can track a global z-index, and each time something is drug, increment the global and assign that to the element's zindex. don't worry about constantly incrementing, z-index can be over a trillion, and their mouse won't last that many clicks...

Comment: @dandavis And how would I do that in terms of code?

Comment: something like `$.zindex=0; ... ondragstart=this.style.zIndex=$.zindex++;` (pseudo code)

Comment: @dandavis And you are sure this would work with draggable `div`s in jquery ui? Because for quite some time now, I've found three `div` classes inside whatever DOM object are made: `ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e`, `ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s`, and `ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se`, they all have a `z-index` of 90.

Comment: you can over-ride that in CSS easy enough, but i think only the outer container, the one actually being moved, needs to have that global z-index set.

Comment: @dandavis thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI draggable has an option called **stack** that can do what you need. Simply set the selector against which the elements need to stack (it doesn't have to be only other draggables), and it'll manage the **z-index** for you. Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    stack: '.draggable'
    });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height:100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="draggable">I am draggable</div>
<div id="div2" class="draggable">I am draggable too!</div>
<div id="div3" class="draggable">Don't forget about me!</div>
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack

Comment: Thanks!!! Although before this, I got a comment saying to increment a gobal `z-index`, on mouse down event. It ended up being a lot more responsive. But thank you for this anyways :)